# Passing values between functions in Angular 1x

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I tryng to count characters from input and if have a number of characters, display a message.

But I don´t know how to pass the value from a function to another. I want pass the message in the HTML with a expression, but I don't know how to pass to $scope.message the other function with the character length;

Am I wrong?

```js
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('LunchChecker', [])

    .controller('LunchCheckerController', LunchCheckerController);

    LunchCheckerController.$inject = ['$scope'];

    function LunchCheckerController($scope) {
        $scope.name = "";
        $scope.totalValue = 0;

        $scope.displayNumeric = function() {

            var totalNameValue = calculateString($scope.name);
            $scope.totalValue = totalNameValue;
            var teste = displayMessage(totalNameValue);
            $scope.sayMessage = teste;

        };

        function displayMessage(quantidade) {
            console.log(quantidade)
            var msg = " "
            if (quantidade <= 30) {
                return msg = "Ok!";
            } else {
                return msg = "Too much!";
            }
        };


        function calculateString(string) {
            var totalStringValue = 0;
            var stringLength = string.length;
            totalStringValue = stringLength;

            return totalStringValue;
        }
    };
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<title>Lunch Checker</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<style>
    .message {
        font-size: 1.3em;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body ng-app="LunchChecker">
<div class="container" ng-controller="LunchCheckerController">
    <h1>Lunch Checker</h1>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input id="lunch-menu" type="text" placeholder="list comma separated dishes you usually have for lunch" class="form-control" ng-model="name" ng-keyup="displayNumeric();">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="displayNumeric();">Check If Too Much</button>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group message">
        <!-- Your message can go here. -->
        {{sayMessage()}}
    </div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overcomplicating it for yourself - you could simply have

```
$scope.sayMessage = function() {
   if($scope.name.length <= 30) {
     return "Ok!";
   } else {
     return  "Too much!";
   }

 };
```

Angular will take care of the synchronization by itself, so you don't need to check the click and keyup events.

If you need to share the variables between the functions for any other reason, you can always just directly use $scope.message - $scope still exists, even when you are in a function (in the same controller).

If you want to share variables between controllers, you can use services

Comment: now I have another doubt, in Javascript when we create a function and wanna to pass a value, we put like arguments function(value1, value2).    I try to catch "return totalStringValue;" with this function function displayMessage(quantidade) {                                                              but  the argument was undefined. This function it's just a test to study.

Comment: @gise I am not sure if I understand it correctly, but If you want the function displayMessage() to receive a parameter, a) define it on the scope ($scope.displayMessage = function()...) and just pass the parameter from the template (i.e. if you want to have scope.message as the parameter, just do something like ng-click="displayMessage(messsage)"

Answer (score 0):

As *Jakub Judas* mentioned: It could be simpler:

```
<!--...-->
<input id="lunch-menu" type="text" ng-model="name"></div>
<div class="form-group message">
  {{name.length<30 ? "Ok" : "Too much"}}
</div>
<!--...-->
```

If you write it that way, you do not need to press a button.

**Update**

I fixed your snippet. You don't call sayMessage. It is a variable which contains a String and not a function.

*And you forgot some `;`.*

```js
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('LunchChecker', [])

    .controller('LunchCheckerController', LunchCheckerController);

    LunchCheckerController.$inject = ['$scope'];

    function LunchCheckerController($scope) {
        $scope.name = "";
        $scope.totalValue = 0;

        $scope.displayNumeric = function() {
            $scope.totalValue = calculateString($scope.name);
            $scope.sayMessage = displayMessage($scope.totalValue);
        };

        function displayMessage(quantidade) {
            console.log(quantidade);
            var msg = " ";
            if (quantidade <= 30) return msg = "Ok!";
            else return msg = "Too much!";
        };

        function calculateString(string) {
            return string.length;
        }
    };
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<title>Lunch Checker</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<style>
    .message {
        font-size: 1.3em;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body ng-app="LunchChecker">
<div class="container" ng-controller="LunchCheckerController">
    <h1>Lunch Checker</h1>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input id="lunch-menu" type="text" placeholder="list comma separated dishes you usually have for lunch" class="form-control" ng-model="name" ng-keyup="displayNumeric();">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="displayNumeric();">Check If Too Much</button>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group message">
        <!-- Your message can go here. -->
        {{sayMessage}}
    </div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

*just a hint: try to avoid many empty lines*

Comment: Thank you, I am still understanding how functions works in Angular. I will remove the empty lines.

Comment: @gise if you think it is correct mark it (or the other answer)